# Need to drop a list of tables and should be made configurable in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

As a part of the new release, occasionally we take backups of few tables and then delete it over a stabilisation period.
I want to make it configurable, that is have a naming convention set up for the list of tables you want to delete and then drop it after the stabilisation period is over

Here is my plan.

1. Rename all the tables which I want to delete, with a suffix say "_TBR" (To be Removed).
2. Add a suffix with yyyymmdd format, eg. if the name of the table is EmployeeDetails, it will be EmployeeDetails_TBR_20150614.

Thus, I will create a stored procedure, that will select all the tables which has a suffix of *TBR* and place it into a temp table, along with date time
eg

```
select 
    name AS 'TableName',
    convert (datetime, substring (name, len(name)-7,8)) as 'DeletedOn'
from 
    sys.tables 
where 
    name like '%_tbr_%' and 
    type ='u'
```

now

```
SELECT TableName FROM #TempTable WHERE DeletedOn <=GETDATE()
```

This will select all the tables that are beyond the specified date.
Now, declare a cursor, and then loop in and delete it.

I will schedule a job to run this stored procedure every week, and it will take care of.

Is there any other smarter and optimized way of doing it?

Comment: what is that select statement is doing while it is giving error in my editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.DropBackupTables
AS

DECLARE @DropScript nvarchar(MAX) = (
    SELECT N'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(name) + N';'
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE
        name LIKE N'%[_]TBR[_][2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]'
        AND RIGHT(name, 8) <= CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)
        FOR XML PATH('')
        );

EXEC sp_executesql @DropScript;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you are over complicating things.
Instead of renaming the tables and using cursors, I would simply add another table to the database, containing the names of the tables that needs to be dropped, and the dates of the drop.
Then I would use a stored procedure to create a dynamic sql to actually drop these tables.
Something like this should do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE TablesToDrop
(
    Table_Name sysname PRIMARY KEY,
    Delete_Date date
)

CREATE PROCEDURE DropTables
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sql varchar(max) = ''

    SELECT @Sql = @Sql + 'DROP TABLE '+ Table_Name +';'
    FROM TablesToDrop
    WHERE Delete_Date <= GETDATE()
    EXEC(@Sql)

END
```

**Note #1:** be very careful about who is going to insert records to this table.

**Note #2:** the last table to be dropped is the TablesToDrop table...